# How do you work with IList<> in F#?

Tags: f#, sum, ilist

I have a list of type `IList<Effort>`. The model Effort contains a `float` called `Amount`. I would like to return the sum of `Amount` for the whole list, in F#. How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
efforts |> Seq.sumBy (fun e -> e.Amount)
```

Comment: Soon after asking the question, I remembered that I should be using Seq instead of List and came to the same conclusion as yours. "member x.TotalEffort = x.Effort |> Seq.sumBy(fun i -> i.Amount)"

Answer (score 5):

Upvoted the answers of `Seq.fold`, pipelined `Seq.fold`, and pipelined `Seq.sumBy` (I like the third one best).

That said, no one has mentioned that `seq<'T>` is F#'s name for `IEnumerable<T>`, and so the `Seq` module functions work on any `IEnumerable`, including `IList`s.

Answer (score 4):

```
Seq.fold (fun acc (effort: Effort) -> acc + effort.Amount) 0.0 efforts
```

Answer (score 4):

One detail that may be interesting is that you can also avoid using type annotations. In the code by *sepp2k*, you need to specify that the `effort` value has a type `Effort`, because the compiler is processing code from the left to the right (and it would fail on the call `effort.Amount` if it didn't know the type). You can write this using pipelining operator:

```
efforts |> Seq.fold (fun acc effort -> acc + effort.Amount) 0.0
```

Now, the compiler knows the type of `effort` because it knows that it is processing a collection `efforts` of type `IList<Effort>`. It's a minor improvement, but I think it's quite nice.